# ga events api - Which guidelines should I follow

Tags: google-analytics, api, event-tracking

this description

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

is slightly different than this

https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api

```
gtag('event', '<event_name>', {<event_params>});
```

particularly the fact that the `value` property needs to be a non-negative integer is ignored in the latter.

Which guidelines should I follow ?

Answer (score 2):

They're both actually the same. The second one in your question is just an abstraction - it shows less data but if you look farther down you can see they're setting `app_name` and `screen_name` where you would be setting `event_category` etc. It just depends on the specific type of event you're tracking and what data you want to capture. For website tracking you'll usually follow the specifics of the first - setting action, category, label, and optionally value gives you the maximum amount of data possible in standard GA event reports.